# Dropdown thymeleaf jpa

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, thymeleaf

I want to create a phone book with a series of data. The requirements are:

- Spring boot
- Thymeleaf
- mySql
- jpa

The problem is, users must have a province from a table in the database different from the contact (to be able to change in the future). My solution has been to add a dropdown with the provinces and add that "Data" to our bbdd by creating a `provincecontact` attribute.

I tried to do this:

```
<select >
<option th:each="provincia : ${provincias}" th:value="${provincia.idprovincia}" th:text="${provincia.provincia}"
th:selected="${provincia.provincia == contactos.provinciacontacto}"></option>
</select>
```

My model:

```
public class Contacto {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="idpersona")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="nombre")
    @NotEmpty(message="Introduce un nombre, por favor")
    @Length(min=3, message="Tu nombre debe tener al menos 3 caracteres")
    private String nombre;
    @Column(name="apellido1")
    private String apellido1;
    @Column(name="apellido2")
    private String apellido2;
    @Column(name="dni")
    private String dni;
    @Column(name="fechanacimiento")
    private Date fechanacimiento;
    @Column(name="telefono1")
    private int telefono1;
    @Column(name="telefono2")
    private int telefono2;
    @Column(name="telefono3")
    private int telefono3;
    @Column(name="telefono4")
    private int telefono4;
    @Column(name="telefono5")
    private int telefono5;
    @Column(name="direccion")
    private String direccion;
    @Column(name="provinciacontacto")
    private String provinciacontacto;
```

My controller:

```
@GetMapping("/addContacto")
    private String redirectContactForm1(@RequestParam(name = "id") int id, Model model) {
        Contacto contacto1 = new Contacto();
        ProvinciasServicesImpl p1=new ProvinciasServicesImpl();

        if (id != 0) {
            contacto1 = contactServices.buscarPorId(id);
        }
        model.addAttribute("contacto1", contacto1);
        model.addAttribute("provincias", provinciasrepo.findAll());
        return "addContacto";

    }
```

With this, I intend to assign the name of the province that has been selected to the `provincecontact` field belonging to the contact table. But I can not make it work.

Everything else works, I create a drop down with the provinces, contacts list edits delete etc. but this brings me head.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to be clearer. But please add more details on the specific problem you are having, and think of a better title for your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

After all it seems to be only a syntax error. Sorry and thanks for your help

In my code i wrote this:

```
<select >
<option th:each="provincia : ${provincias}" th:value="${provincia.idprovincia}" th:text="${provincia.provincia}"
th:selected="${provincia.provincia == contactos.provinciacontacto}"></option>
</select>
```

and I should have written:

```
<select  ***th:field="*{provincia}***">
<option th:each="provincia : ${provincias}" th:value="${provincia.idprovincia}" th:text="${provincia.provincia}"
th:selected="${provincia.provincia == contactos.provinciacontacto}"></option>
</select>
```